# Randomized String & UIImageView together

Tags: ios, swift, random, uiimageview

I'm working on an app which lets users have randomized data when you shake your device.

I have 4 arrays to hold the string data and function which creates randomized number;

```
let characters = ["Zoolog", "Xander"]

let problems = ["Asteroid", "Dr Evil"]

let places = ["Vast Desert", "Ice Caves"]

let time = ["Wednesday 12th, 1220", "1236"]



func randomCharacter() -> String {

    let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: characters.count)

    return characters[randomNumber]

}

func randomPlaces() -> String {

    let randomNumberOne = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: places.count)

    return places[randomNumberOne]
}

func randomProblems() -> String {

    let randomNumberTwo = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: problems.count)

    return problems[randomNumberTwo]

}

func randomTime() -> String {

    let randomNumberThree = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: time.count)

    return time[randomNumberThree]
}
```

On my viewController, data is randomized and users get a randomized data on their screen once they shake their devices.

```
 override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.motionShake) {

        characterName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomCharacter()
        placeName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomPlaces()
        problemName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomProblems()
        timeName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomTime()

    }
}
```

I also have an imageView for the character picture. So once the data is randomized I would like my users to see the characters and their names as well. But at the moment, I can only randomize the imageView and characters **separately not together**.

I've gone through some sample codes but couldn't understand how to approach this.

--Updated
Note: I don't have a problem with the code I have. I don't know how to randomize the characterImageView to match with the characterName. So if a picture belongs to a character in my character array then the nameLabel and imageView should match.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    super.becomeFirstResponder()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    characterImageView.image = UIImage(named: "elegantEmma")
    placeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zombieLand")
    problemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "meteor")
    timeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "time")

    //First random value shown on the launch
    characterName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomCharacter()
    placeName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomPlaces()
    problemName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomProblems()
    timeName.text = myStoryCharacters.randomTime()
```

Comment: where is `imageView`? what are `characterName`, `placeName`, `problemName` and `timeName` ?

Comment: You need to show the code you are using for the `UIImageView` as well, at the moment its not clear exactly what the problem is

Comment: I've added the imageView part and more explanation regarding what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the image names in arrays as well, so for example for your characters have...

```
let characters = ["Zoolog", "Xander"]
let characterImages = ["ZoologImage", "XanderImage"]   // These relate to the image names in your assets

func randomCharacter() -> String {

    let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: characters.count)

    characterImageView.image = UIImage(named: characterImages[randomNumber])

    return characters[randomNumber]

}
```

Then do the same for the other arrays, you could also change the random functions to set the text and not bother returning it, unless of course you need it for something else